# ERROR When trying to insert into MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what's wrong with my syntax, but I'm missing something:

```
$createrequest = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products_updates_queue (id, kid,
product_version_id, key, ip) VALUES ('$request_id', '$uid', '$version_id',
'$request_key', '$request_ip')");
```

I receive this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, ip) VALUES ('j4ctveyd0x62', '1', 'z451ah3', 'hqbyu7bhg8za', '64.134.163.2' at line 2"

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Avoid it, or wrap it in backticks.

Edit: And I hope you escaped the variables you're putting into that query.

Answer (score 6):

I think `key` is a reserved word, and you should avoid using it as a column name. Try using backticks around it:

```
$createrequest = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products_updates_queue (id, uid, product_version_id, `key`, ip) VALUES ('$request_id', '$uid', '$version_id', '$request_key', '$request_ip')");
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting avoiding using it as a column name (Better  solution then always having to wrap it in backticks)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I saw the solution from @DCoder before yours, but I will accept yours so that others (if they have the same problem), will know to avoid using this column name.

Comment: The other user also tells you to avoid it. Feel free to accept the answer you like the most!